# Visually and audibly unambiguous subset of the Latin alphabet?

Tags: design

Imagine you give someone a card with the code "5SBDO0" on it.

In some fonts, the letter "S" is difficult to visually distinguish from the number five, (as with number zero and letter "O").

Reading the code out loud, it might be difficult to distinguish "B" from "D", necessitating saying "B as in boy," "D as in dog," or using a "[phonetic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)" instead.

What's the biggest subset of letters and numbers that will, in most cases, both look unambiguous visually and sound unambiguous when read aloud?

---

Background:

We want to generate a short string that can encode as many values as possible while still being easy to communicate.

Imagine you have a 6-character string, "123456".  In base 10 this can encode **10**^6 values.

In hex "1B23DF" you can encode **16**^6 values in the same number of characters, but this can sound ambiguous when read aloud. ("B" vs. "D")

Likewise for any string of N characters, you get (size of alphabet)^N values.

The string is limited to a length of about six characters, due to wanting to fit easily within the capacity of [human working memory capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory#Capacity).

Thus to find the max number of values we can encode, we need to find that largest unambiguous set of letters/numbers.  There's no reason we can't consider the letters G-Z, and some common punctuation, but I don't want to have to go manually pairwise compare "does G sound like A?", "does G sound like B?", "does G sound like C" myself.  As we know this would be O(n^2) linguistic work to do =)...

Comment: Note that what letters are pronounced similar can differ a lot between languages...

Comment: Besides, what exactly is _the_ Latin alphabet?

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073956/how-to-generate-63-million-prize-codes/1074083#1074083) in a related StackOverflow question.

Comment: For the visual distinction, [Base 32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) is a standard encoding that limits the similarities of the symbols.

Comment: @MSalters The "Latin script" is a linguistics idea, for our purposes I really just mean "select from the subset of the Latin script that is codified into Unicode," e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: @elliot42: You know that there are [16 Latin ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_characters_in_Unicode) in Unicode?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should partition the set of alphanumerics into groups by visual similarity, and choose a “most iconic” representative from each group. This is somewhat subjective, though you could run user tests on it. The choices you make also depend on whether the figures will be printed or handwritten. For example:

- { **O**, **0**, **Q**, **D** }
- { **I**, **L**, **1** }
- { **B**, **8** }
- { **Z**, **2** }
- { **S**, **5** }
- { **7**, **T** }
- { **U**, **V**, **Y** }

Similarly, partition characters by the phonetic similarity of their names’ pronunciations:

- { **A** [ʔeɪ], **8** [ʔeɪ(ʔ/t)] }
  = starts with [ʔeɪ]
- { **P** [pi:], **B** [bi:], **V** [vi:], **D** [di:], **T** [ti:], **E** [ʔi:] }
  = stop/fricative + [i:]
- { **G** [ʤi:], **C** [si:], **Z** [zi:], **3** [θɹi:] }
  = fricative/affricate (cluster) + [i:]
- { **M** [ɛm], **N** [ɛn] }
  = [ɛ] + nasal
- { **S** [ɛs], **F** [ɛf], **X** [ɛks] }
  = [ɛ] + fricative/affricate
- { **I** [ʔaɪ], **Y** [waɪ], **5** [faɪv], **9** [naɪn] }
  = consonant + [aɪ] + (consonant)
- { **Q** [kjʉ:], **U** [jʉ:], **2** [t(j)ʉ:] }
  = consonant + [(j)ʉ:]

These are, of course, not the only possible partitions, just what come to mind at the moment. Regardless, they should be enough to get you started for further testing. Also, these aren’t backed up by any professional sources—I cite only my hobbyist backgrounds in typography and phonetics.

Comment: For a start with Auditory similarity, have a look at radio communications such as Air traffic Control operations manuals( where verbal communications must be correctly interpreted or people die) and Ham Radio. 
For instance 5 and 9 are easy to mix up, hence spoken as "five" and "nine-a"

Comment: @mattnz: Thanks, I forgot 5 and 9. Audio quality is a big factor as well: radios, telephones, studio recordings, and in-person communications all pose their own unique problems.

Comment: Technically that's "niner," four is "fower."

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) to have real people rate all 26^2 pairs of letters for aural and visual similarity. The advantage is that you could even get data for various native languages this way.

Answer (score 1):

For English, the [soundex](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) and [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) algorithms encode which sounds are ambiguous. Soundex is probably too simple, but Metaphone incorporates some good points.  Do you want the sequence "OU" ? That could be pronounced in many ways, as this sentence demontrates ;)

Answer (score 0):

Jon Purdy's answer above seems most correct.  For practical purposes, I am trying `z-base-32`, a non-standard base32 encoding designed with communicability in mind.  It looks functional, though not ideal--e.g. they explicitly didn't focus on spoken disambiguation.

http://philzimmermann.com/docs/human-oriented-base-32-encoding.txt

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbase32/